# Extract a string between other two in Python

Tags: python, pdf, python-re

I am trying to extract the comments from a fdf (PDF comment file). In practice, this is to extract a string between other two. I did the following:

1. I open the fdf file with the following command:

```
import re
import os

os.chdir("currentworkingdirectory")
archcom =open("comentarios.fdf", "r")
cadena = archcom.read()
```

2. With the opened file, I create a string called cadena with all the info I need. For example:

```
cadena = "\n215 0 obj\n<</D[2.0 2.0]/S/D>>\nendobj\n216 0 obj\n<</D[2.0 2.0]/S/D>>\nendobj\n217 0 obj\n<</D[2.0 2.0]/S/D>>\nendobj\n218 0 obj\n<</W 3.0>>\nendobj\n219 0 obj\n<</W 3.0>>\nendobj\ntrailer\n<</Root 1 0 R>>\n%%EOF\n"
```

3. I try to extract the needed info with the following line:

```
a = re.findall(r"nendobj(.*?)W 3\.0",cadena)
```

Trying to get:

```
a = "n216 0 obj\n<</D[2.0 2.0]/S/D>>\nendobj\n217 0 obj\n<</D[2.0 2.0]/S/D>>\nendobj\n218 0 obj\n<<"
```

But I got:

```
a = []
```

The problem is in the line `a = re.findall(r"nendobj(.*?)W 3\.0",cadena)` but I don't realize where. I have tried many combinations with no success.

I appreciate any comment.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are 2 problems:

a) you are looking for `nendobj`, but the N is actually part of the line break `\n`. Thus you'll also not get a leading N in the output, because there is no N.

b) Since the text you're looking for crosses some newlines, you need the `re.DOTALL` flag

Final code:

```
a = re.findall("endobj(.*?)W 3\.0",cadena, re.DOTALL)
```

Also note, that there will be a second result, [confirmed by Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5CjvbX/1).